# Why webpack is compressing my bundle by default

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, gzip, brotli

In the company Im currently working for there is a react app that uses webpack 5.
The webpack config file is like this:

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const ModuleFederationPlugin = require("webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const path = require("path");
const deps = require("./package.json").dependencies;
const dotenv = require("dotenv").config();

module.exports = (env = {}) => {
  const mode = env.NODE_ENV === "prod" ? "production" : "development";

  return {
    entry: "./src/index",
    mode: mode,
    devtool: mode === "production" ? false : "source-map",
    devServer: {
      static: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
      port: 3000,
      hot: true,
      historyApiFallback: true,
      client: {
        overlay: false,
      },
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'], 
    },
    output: {
      publicPath: "/",
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.tsx?$/,  // TypeScript loader
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: 'ts-loader',
        },
        { test: /\.m?js/, type: "javascript/auto" },
        {
          test: /\.m?js/,
          resolve: {
            fullySpecified: false,
          },
        },
        {
          test: /\.m?js$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: {
            loader: "babel-loader",
            options: {
              presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
              plugins: [
                "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
                "@babel/plugin-transform-async-to-generator",
                "@babel/plugin-syntax-jsx",
                "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
              ],
            },
          },
        },
        {
          test: /\.scss$/,
          use: [
            mode !== "production"
              ? "style-loader"
              : MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            "css-loader",
            "sass-loader",
          ],
        },
        {
          test: /\.css$/,
          use: [
            mode !== "production"
              ? "style-loader"
              : MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            "css-loader",
          ],
        },
        {
          test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif|ico)$/,
          use: ["file-loader"],
        },
        {
          test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: "file-loader",
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          test: /\.json$/,
          loader: "json-loader",
        },
        {
          test: /\.txt$/i,
          use: "raw-loader",
        },
      ],
    },
    plugins: [
      new ModuleFederationPlugin({
        name: "mainApp",
        library: { type: "var", name: "mainApp" },
        remotes: {
          linkManagement: "linkManagement",
        },
        shared: {
          "react-router-dom": {
            singleton: true,
          },
          "react-dom": {
            singleton: true,
          },
          react: {
            requiredVersion: deps.react,
            singleton: true,
          },
          "component-lib": {
            singleton: true,
          },
        },
      }),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: "./public/index.html",
      }),
      new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: "[name].css",
        chunkFilename: "[id].css",
      }),
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        VERSION: JSON.stringify("3.0.67"),
        ENV: JSON.stringify(env.NODE_ENV),
        AUTH0_CONFIG_DOMAIN: JSON.stringify(process.env.AUTH0_CONFIG_DOMAIN),
        //some other env vars here
      }),
    ],
  };
};
```

The app is rather slow so I thought about compressing the bundle using gzip. Before doing that I wanted to see how much space and how long does it take to fetch the bundle. When I build the app I see the /dist directory is created and there is a file called main.js (among others). When I run the app I go to localhost:3000 and I see in the network request that main.js file being fetched. However, I already see this in the Response Headers

```
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

I see no files that end in .gz in the /dist directory. Why is this main.js app being gzipped by default?

In the docs it specically says that if you want to compress you need to install a plugin

https://webpack.js.org/plugins/compression-webpack-plugin/

If I go ahead and install the plugin and copy the code provided by the docs I can successfully see the files ending in .gz in my /dist directory. However, when I go to localhost:3000 the manin.js file has the same size and takes the same time as before.

Am I missing something?

Comment: If the static files are "delivered" directly through the webserver (like apache, nginx, haproxy, ...), then the compression is likely done by that part. But even if those act only as a reverse proxy, then the response will (if not already compressed) will be compressed by the server.

Comment: Is there a way to know where or how the static files are delivered from the app repository? there is a devops team and I guess they manage that but dont want to bother them with my noob questions

Comment: Open the `main.js` in a text editor. Is it still a text file? If yes, then the server delivers content zipped for you. Also check other resources in the network tab. The browser is likely sending `Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br` or similar and the server, if configured for it, will transfer minimized files. Your local development server will be configured differently from the live server, better ask the devops team if that's configured. You can also check your network tab on the live site. Still doesn't hurt to minimize the js file, then likely called `main.min.js`.

Comment: You are right, the browser is sending `Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br`. Isn't the minification done automatically by webpack 5 in production mode? thats what the teacher said in my udemy course :p

Comment: Optimizing a huge js based webapp for the best user experience is a complex topic. One of the problems that might exist is that all resulting js code is bundled in one output file, even if for the initial display of the site, only a small portion is needed, splitting it into meaningful chunks can already greatly improve the user experience.

Comment: `Isn't the minification done automatically by webpack 5 in production mode?` that's pretty easy to check, look at the resulting file ;)